# Chinese passports + A residence permit issued by France: Do I need a visa traveling to South Korea?

Tags: visas, europe, south-korea, chinese-citizens, permits

Excerpt from [Wikipedia: Visa policy of South Korea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_South_Korea)

> Holders of **Chinese passports** who also hold a physical visa or **a residence permit issued by a EEA** member state or Switzerland, or a group visa issued by Japan and traveling with the tour group, can also enjoy visa-free transit for 30 days.

I have Chinese passport and a residence permit issued by France. Can I enjoy visa-free transit for 30 days if I travel to South Korea **independently**?

My scheduling is,

- outbound: France --> China (Stay a couple of days)
- inbound:  China --> South Korea (Stay less than 10 days) --> France

Comment: To be clear, are you transiting South Korea (say, flying from China to South Korea to France)?

Comment: @ZachLipton, many thanks for your kind reminder. I've just edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you may enjoy visa-free transit for 30 days. There is sightly different wording provided courtesy [KLM](https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/visaform.htm):

Korea (Rep.) (KR)

Visa Exemptions:

- Nationals of China (People's Rep.) with a visa issued by Australia, Canada, New Zealand, Switzerland, USA or an EEA Member State if in transit through Korea
  (Rep.):

  - holding confirmed onward tickets on flights departing within 30 days; when
  - arriving from a third country, departing to the country that issued the visa (e.g. PVG-ICN-SFO); or
  - arriving on a direct flight from the country that issued
    the visa (a visa that expired on departure from that country
    is accepted), departing to a third country (e.g. SFO-ICN-PVG).

.

Not applicable if traveling in a group.
  Not applicable if traveling from/to Northern Mariana Isl.
  Not applicable to holders of an e-visa.

Comment: Many thanks. The site [KLM: Travel documents](https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/visaform.htm) is quite convenent. In my case, what do you choose for the field **Embarkation**?